# How do I extend this mergeWords function to any number of strings?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, purely-functional

Following is the mergeWords function.

```
mergeWords [] [] = []
mergeWords [] (y:ys) = y:'\n':(mergeWords [] ys)
mergeWords (x:xs) [] = x:'\n':(mergeWords xs [])
mergeWords (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:y:'\n':(mergeWords xs ys)
```

If applied on `mergeWords "hello" "world"` it gives

```
"hw\neo\nlr\nll\nod\n"
```

I can't figure out how to extend this to list of strings. Like applying it to 3 strings should first take first character of each of the strings and then put a '\n' and then the second character and so on.

Comment: Well that is up to you to decide: how to *generalize* the function. But your generalization makes sense, yes.

Comment: I think your example is incorrect. Is it a result on calling it on `"howdie" "world"`?

Comment: sorry about that corrected it to the result for hello world

Comment: I tried using something like `map head ["hello", "world"]` which returns `"hw"` but i am not able to make this recursive. How do i generate a list that has dropped h and w and apply same map head to it.

Comment: Check out `transpose` in `Data.List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds reasonably easy if you do it in steps:

```
cutWords :: [String] -> [[String]]    -- ["ab", "cd", "e"] -> [["a", "c", "e"], ["b", "d"]]
concatWord :: [String] -> String       -- ["a", "c", "e"] -> "ace\n"
concatWords :: [String] -> String    -- use mergeWord on all of them
```

The most interesting part is of course the `cutWords` part. What you want there is a zip-like behaviour, and for that it'll help if we "safe" `tail` and `head`:

```
head' (x:xs) = [x]
head' "" = ""

tail' (x:xs) = xs
tail' "" = ""
```

Now we can implement our `cutWords`, making sure we stop in time:

```
cutWords xs = heads : rest
  where
    heads = map head' xs
    tails = map tail' xs
    rest = if any (/= "") tails then cutWords tails
                                else []
```

Then the remaining part is trivial:

```
concatWord word = concat word ++ "\n"
concatWords words = concatMap concatWord word
```

Answer (score 4):

The puzzle is effectively to merge a *list* of words, a character at a time, into lines with trailing newline characters.

```
mergeWords :: [String] -> String
```

We need to take a list like

```
[ "hello"
, "jim"
, "nice"
, "day"
]
```

and rearrange it into the lists of things at a given position

```
[ "hjnd"
, "eiia"
, "lmcy"
, "le"
, "o"
]
```

That's what the library function `transpose` does.

And then we need to make a single string which treats those as lines, separated by newlines. Which is what `unlines` does.

So

```
mergeWords = unlines . transpose
```

and we're done.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I am trying write transpose function myself.